# Sound Settings change on any restart or lock

Tags: sound

I am using the audio from my hdmi monitors. If I click on settings->Sound->Output, I have 4 choices:
1 .  Digital Output(S/PDIF)->Family 17h (Models 00h-ofh)HD Audio Controller
2.   HDMI/Display Port 3 GP104 High Definition Audio Controller
3.   HDMI/Display Port 2 GP104 High Definition Audio Controller
4.   HDMI/Display Port GP104 High Definition Audio Controller

The sound works as long as I select a monitor.  The problem is that every time the computer goes to sleep or I restart, UBUNTU forgets the settings and it goes back to option #1, which produces no sound because I dont have speaker connected to my sound outputs.

Thank you